# PowerShell Remote MSU Install - syntax is incorrect

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell to install a MSU file but receiving a unusual error. This error only shows itself when running the code below remotely using Invoke-Command.

Any ideas on what this could be?

```
Write-Host "Downloading file..."
if((Test-Path -Path "C:\Temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu") -eq $true) { Remove-Item -Path "C:\Temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu" }
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839516" -OutFile "C:\Temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu"

if((Test-Path -Path "C:\Temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu") -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "Installing file..."
    wusa /PackagePath:C:\Temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu /quiet /norestart
} else {
    Write-Host "File not downloaded"
}
```

Error

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. At
line:1 char:9
+         $results = Invoke-Command -Computername $Computer -Credential ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The filename, d...x is incorrect.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Are you running PS a Admin?  You need to start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Make sure on remote machine there is a c:\TEMP folder (not TMP).  You are trying to update a Win8 machine which Microsoft prohibits  updates.

Comment: The error message shows different code than the code you have posted..

Comment: @jdweng Yes PS is running as admin

Comment: @Theo, you need to explain in more detail what your looking at

Comment: What I said.. The error is about `Invoke-Command`, but you left that part out of the code you show, so we have nothing to help you with